# Unable to compile code generated using gradle-swagger-generator-plugin

Tags: gradle, code-generation, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, codegen

I am facing a problem that code generated using gradle-swagger-generator-plugin is not compiling due to unresolved dependencies.

I have a multimodule gradle project with the following folder structure. *parent* is the parent project with three subprojects named *modules:apis*, *modules:api-client*, and *modules:common*

```
.
├── parent
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gbuild
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper
│   │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── apis
│   │   │   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   │   │   ├── gbuild
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   ├── api-client (generated)
│   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   │   ├── build.sbt
│   │   │   ├── docs
│   │   │   ├── gbuild
│   │   │   ├── git_push.sh
│   │   │   ├── gradle
│   │   │   ├── gradle.properties
│   │   │   ├── gradlew
│   │   │   ├── gradlew.bat
│   │   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   │   ├── settings.gradle
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   └── common
│   │       ├── build.gradle.kts
│   │       ├── gbuild
│   │       └── src
│   ├── project_version.properties
│   └── settings.gradle.kts
```

Module *:modules:apis* is the spring boot REST service for which I want to generate client SDK. Module *:modules:api-client* is the placeholder project wherein the client code is generated.

Relevant sections from the `modules/apis/build.gradle.kts` are as given below.

```
plugins {
// Some plugins omitted for clarity
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
 
    id("org.hidetake.swagger.generator") version "2.18.2"
}

dependencies {
    // Other dependencies omitted
    implementation (Libs.io_swagger_core)
    swaggerCodegen("io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.27")
}

swaggerSources {
    create("testcode") {
        // File api-spec is already generated and placed at the right location.
        setInputFile(file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/swagger/api-spec.json"))
        code(
            closureOf<org.hidetake.gradle.swagger.generator.GenerateSwaggerCode> {
                wipeOutputDir = true
                language = "java"
                configFile = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/swagger/api-config.json")
                outputDir = file(
                    "$rootDir/modules/client"
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

tasks.named("build") { dependsOn("generateSwaggerCode") }
```

*What works:* I can generate client code using `gradle clean build` in `modules\apis` and build it using `.\gradle.bat clean build` or using `gradle clean build` in `modules\api-client`.

**What does not work:** When I build the *parent* project using `.\gradlew build --no-daemon --stacktrace --info` in the parent folder, the task `:modules:api-client:compileJava` fails with compiler errors **only for the first run**. Compilation fails because gradle fails to resolve dependencies from `modules\api-client\build.gradle`. Compiler errors can be found in the attached file.

However, subsequent builds using the same command succeed without problem until modules\api-client folder is deleted manually.

Gradle version used by the *parent* project

```
\path\to\parent> .\gradlew.bat --version                                                                                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Gradle version used by *:modules:api-client* subproject

```
\path\to\parent\modules\api-client> .\gradlew.bat --version                                                                                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-08-10 13:15:06 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     233bbf8e47c82f72cb898b3e0a96b85d0aad166e

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I have tried this with all four combinations of options `--build-cache` and `--no-parallel` but got the same result. I am relatively new to gradle and took a wild guess that these two options may be playing role in this problem.

Any help in resolving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

You should put the generated classes in the `buildDir` (since you don't want to modifiy them as they get regenerated at each build) and then you need to add the generated class to your sourceSet.

In your `build.gradle.kts` add this:

```kotlin
configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/src/main/java")
    }
}
```

With the path being the one you specify in your swagger generation task.
Also on my case I set the dependency on the `KotlinCompile` task:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    dependsOn("generateSwaggerCode")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

Make sure that this "generateSwaggerCode" does generate the code you need though (`./gradlew generateSwaggerCode`)